# QuickBlox - the first of the two users doesn't receive the video

Tags: video-streaming, quickblox

On some occasions, user A calls user B and user A cannot see person B. They can hear each other and user B sees user A, but not the other way around.

Both user A and user B can see their local video track.

Comment: Which platform and SDK version do you use? What are the exact reproduction steps? What your logs show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our problem was that we were using AVMediaSession in a different view and it interfered with the quickblox one.

The solution is to stop all the other camera sessions before starting a quickblox call.